# Why A.class is null in run time?

Tags: java

I meet a problem when using A.class in program and it return java.lang.NullPointerException at run-time
This is my snipped code:

```
public synchronized boolean isDeviceEqual(IDevice dev) {
  ............
  if( isDeviceInstanceOf(SimpleDevice.class) ) {
      return dev instanceof IDevice
            && XXX();
  }
  ............
}
public boolean isDeviceInstanceOf(Class cls) {
    return cls.isAssignableFrom(mDeviceClass);
}
```

and NPE

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at xxx/library/DeviceDescriptor.isDeviceInstanceOf(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z (:0:5)
at xxx/library/DeviceDescriptor.isDeviceEqual(LIDevice;)Z (:0:6)
```

with above NPE, it means that cls is null in this case but I can't explain why this happens so can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

`cls.isAssignableFrom(mDeviceClass)` will throw a NullPointerException if `mDeviceClass`, which must be the case here, since you are sure that `cls` is not null.

```
/**
 * Determines if the class or interface represented by this
 * <code>Class</code> object is either the same as, or is a superclass or
 * superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified
 * <code>Class</code> parameter. It returns <code>true</code> if so;
 * otherwise it returns <code>false</code>. If this <code>Class</code>
 * object represents a primitive type, this method returns
 * <code>true</code> if the specified <code>Class</code> parameter is
 * exactly this <code>Class</code> object; otherwise it returns
 * <code>false</code>.
 *
 * <p> Specifically, this method tests whether the type represented by the
 * specified <code>Class</code> parameter can be converted to the type
 * represented by this <code>Class</code> object via an identity conversion
 * or via a widening reference conversion. See <em>The Java Language
 * Specification</em>, sections 5.1.1 and 5.1.4 , for details.
 * 
 * @param cls the <code>Class</code> object to be checked
 * @return the <code>boolean</code> value indicating whether objects of the
 * type <code>cls</code> can be assigned to objects of this class
 * @exception NullPointerException if the specified Class parameter is
 *            null.
 * @since JDK1.1
 */
public native boolean isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls);
```

It seems strange that in `isDeviceEqual(IDevice dev)` you are not doing anything with `dev`. I don't know what `mDeviceClass` is, but perhaps it should be assigned `dev.getClass()` somewhere.

Comment: Thank Eran, dev is used to check instance of IDevice

Comment: Thank Eran, dev is used to check instance of IDevice but it does not relate to isDeviceInstanceOf(). NPE is thrown when program running and it happens once only. Thanks.